# How to dynamically align text in a card?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm facing a problem with text alignment in the card widget on Flutter. I'm not able to properly align my text due to the set directives (ex.:'Alignment.topCenter').

Here my main widget code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Container _titleContainer() => Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('My Text Title',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white)),
            Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 16,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  ///Return a container with the title layout
  Container _subtitleContainer() => Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('My Text Subtitle',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white)),
            Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 16,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyCard(
              mainTitle: _titleContainer(),
              subtTitle: _subtitleContainer(),
              titleTextAlignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              subtitleTextAlignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
            MyCard(
              mainTitle: _titleContainer(),
              subtTitle: _subtitleContainer(),
              titleTextAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              subtitleTextAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Here the card widget code

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Container mainTitle;
  final Container subtTitle;

  ///Card desidered height. Else default 250
  final double height;

  ///Image scale factor
  final int scaleFactor;

  final bool linearGradient;

  final Alignment titleTextAlignment;

  final Alignment subtitleTextAlignment;

  const MyCard(
      {Key key,
      this.mainTitle,
      this.subtTitle,
      this.height,
      this.scaleFactor = 1,
      this.linearGradient = true,
      this.titleTextAlignment = Alignment.bottomLeft,
      this.subtitleTextAlignment = Alignment.bottomLeft})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 8,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: height != null && height > 0 ? height : 250.0,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                // FutureBuilder(
                //   future: ,
                //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
                //     switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                //       case ConnectionState.none:
                //       case ConnectionState.active:
                //       //Show a card with FCSBlue background
                //       case ConnectionState.waiting:
                //         return FCSLoader();
                //       case ConnectionState.done:
                //         if (snapshot.hasError) {
                //           return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                //         } else {
                //           final String imgStringUrl = snapshot.data;

                //           return Image(
                //             image: AdvancedNetworkImage(
                //               imgStringUrl,
                //               useDiskCache: true,
                //               cacheRule:
                //                   CacheRule(maxAge: const Duration(days: 7)),
                //             ),
                //             fit: BoxFit.cover,
                //           );
                //         }
                //     }
                //   },
                // ),
                linearGradient == true
                    ? Container(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: new LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
                            colors: [Colors.green, Colors.transparent],
                          ),
                        ),
                        // borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(...),
                        // gradient: new LinearGradient(...),
                      )
                    : Container(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(32, 38, 48, 0.6),
                      ),
                Align(
                  alignment: titleTextAlignment,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: mainTitle != null ? mainTitle : Text('')),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: subtitleTextAlignment,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                      child: subtTitle != null ? subtTitle : Text('')),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the first card I expect that the text is aligned like showed with the red points. In the second card I have the same previous problem, but in this case I obtain a overlying text. I would like that the text will arrange like in a ListView/Column.

**My Sample :**

[image]

Hope I was clear. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Align put your text widget inside

```
FractionalTranslation(
  translation: Offset(dx, dy),
  //add your text widget to child
  //child:
),
```

What `dx` and `dy` are offset are factional horizontal and vertical distance in their respective direction. The

I would say that you play around with these and you will understand yourself.

Like start with `Offset(0.0,0.0)`

then change it to `Offset(0.0,1)`

and compare both results hopefully you will understand it.

Comment: It doesn't work because the offset is different in every device. The card widget width change in every device. And it change already when your device is landscape/portrait

Comment: It should work every the same because sets values percentage, not a based corded pixel values. Your widget structure is probably wrong or something has an unbounded height/width. I can't help you much eight now, currently mobile.

Comment: I think too that there is a problem in the layout tree. Because I expect that with the Align widget, when I set the alignment property, the text change its position in considering all the card area. But it seems like the Align widget hasn't all Stack widget area to move the text like set by alignment directives